# how to remove item from one combobox

Tags: combobox, asp.net-3.5

hi i m using 5 combobox in my asp.net 3.5 c# project .here i want remove item from other combobox which item is selected in other combobox.

Comment: just google it ;)

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/19fc31ss%28VS.85%29.aspx

Comment: You'll need to be a little more clearer, you have 5 combo boxes is the content of all the comboboxes the same?

Comment: A ComboBox in asp.net, are you using the ComboBox from the ajax toolkit? as I don't believe there is a ComboBox control in asp.net.

Answer (score 0):

In the OnSelectedIndexChanged event, just call the comoboBox.Items.Remove method.

As the commenter below points out, make sure you set AutoPostBack = True so events fire when you actually change your selection.

Comment: i think this will only work when `AutoPostBack` is set to `true`